# Is the integral of a non elementary integral also non elementary?

Tags: integration, differential-algebra

Consider a non elementary integral with an integrand like $\frac{\exp(x)}{x}$ or $\exp(\exp(x))$. Is the indefinite integral of such functions necessarily non elementary ?

Comment: If the integral were elementary, then the integrand is the integral's derivative which is elementary as well

Comment: @RichardChen Thank you I notice now how easy the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-elementary integral gives you a non-elementary function. For example: $$\int\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$Is a non-elementary function. Taking the integral of a non-elementary function results in a non-elementary integral (as given in one of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164890/how-can-we-prove-that-any-integral-in-the-set-of-non-elementary-integrals-cannot))

Comment: Thank you stack exchange did not suggest that link among the first few suggestions when I wrote the question. I should have searched directly.

Comment: @userrandrand Sometimes titles in Stack-exchange aren't easily searchable. Also, you could upvote and accept an answer if you like it :)